# Redirect url in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Good morning,

I´ve been looking my Spring security configuration, I´m wondering how I could redirect to a specific url all paths that are pointing to for example /foo/*.
I need to do something similar as we do when there´s no session, and we redirect to the login page.

In my case I need that whatever url that is pointing to /foo/* would be redirect to a in_development_page.html.

I would like to use the intercept pattern if would be possible, something like this.

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/foo/*" redirect="in_development_page.html"/>
```

Do you know if something like this it´s possible?.

Regards.

Comment: in_development_page.html seems your login page. You just need to make /foo/* authorized access only(by isAuthorized() or similar methods) in <intercept-url>. Spring security will redirect to login page on unauthorized access.

Comment: I already have a login page when we dont have session. Now we have a demo to the client where we dont want to show them a secction of the application, and I was looking for an easy solution with Spring security, instead have to remove part of the application and create a version for them. The PO wants that if you click in that secction of the application a "in development" page must be showed as I explain in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use interceptor for it :

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/foo/**"/>            
    <bean class="com.interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

suppose we want to check session then you can write code in `AuthorizationInterceptor` like :

```
    if(UserSession.isSessionValid()){
        System.out.println("ready to enter");
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("not logged in...redirecting to login");
        response.sendRedirect("/in_development_page");
        return false;
    }
```

here `UserSession` is my class that have session variables.

if you just want to redirect then you can remove code of `if` & only pass `response.sendRedirect()`.
in parameter pass the page `URL` of under development.

full class code :

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private IUserSession UserSession;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("interceptor called for " + request.getRequestURI());
        if(UserSession.isSessionValid()){
            System.out.println("ready to enter");
            return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("not logged in...redirecting to login");
            response.sendRedirect("/in_development_page");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

here class will extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` spring class.

Comment: Good approach but I was wondering if Spring data dont have a redirect system already instead have to code by myself

Comment: @paul : If you still want more customization then visit http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/ or let me post within few minutes. thanks.

Comment: Do you know which tags and schemas I need in order to use the interceptor in my Spring configuration?, I´m using Spring MVC 3.2